# I want to make a changing "array" of color options and size options per item in the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, bootstrap-4

Title and code. I'm working on an E-Commerce site where I will have multiple options per item (color/size). In the code you can see price, price(1-3), the idea is to create a button or option for the admin to add additional sizes and therefor prices without hard coding sizename(1-4) and the same goes for colorName(1-4). I hope that you can understand what I'm going for, I just started learning  python and all of this bootstrap and django stuff yesterday. BTW If you know of an easier way to handle all of this, please do let me know, I'm lost as to how to make a shopping cart.

I just started this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    category = models.CharField(choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=25, default='Default')
    multSizes = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    numberSizes = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price1 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=0)
    price2 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=0)
    price3 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=0)
    sizename1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    sizename2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    sizename3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    sizename4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    numberColors = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    colorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    colorName1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    colorName2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    colorName3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    colorName4 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
```

I want to be able to change the amount of different sizes/prices and the amount of colors through the django admin panel. I do not want to hard code the fields as I have there right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply have a single "color" & "size" field for the `Product` model, you could create multiple instances of the model with different properties.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    category = models.CharField(choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=25, default='Default')
    sizename = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    colorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
```

```sh
>>> p1 = Product(name="shirt", price=10, sizename="M", colorname="red")
>>> p2 = Product(name="pants", price=20, sizename="M", colorname="yellow")
```

However, I think the issue that you are getting at is that for a product with a single set of some properties-- `name`, `price`, `stock`, `image_url`, and `category`-- there are multiple sizes and colors. Is that correct?

If so, you could still create multiple instances that share those properties:

```sh
>>> p1 = Product(name="shirt", price=10, sizename="M", colorname="red")
>>> p2 = Product(name="shirt", price=10, sizename="L", colorname="yellow")
```

However, in database design, this is not considered *"normal form."* [See: Second Normal Form (Wikipedia).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)

A better design might be to pull those attributes into a separate table, ie, a second Django model, that references the first model with a foreign key. Something like this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    category = models.CharField(choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=25, default='Default')


class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sizename = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
    colorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='N/A')
```

For more info, see the Django docs on [many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How would I go about using the latter option. Specifically, how would I add the variants in the admin panel?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for the [Django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/). If you want to be able to add `ProductVariant` objects from the `Product` edit page, maybe take a look at the section on [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).